# Run existing Cocos2d-x project in Android

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am staring cocos2d-x development.

I have made one demo cocos2d-x project in xcode using cocos2d-x template. Now i want to use that existing project for android. How can i use that existing project for android? Can Anyone please guide me or give some link for this issue ? any kind of guidance will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can follow this beautiful Tutorial : http://www.raywenderlich.com/33750/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-getting-started

Comment: i have followed that link, in that they have made two separate project for iphone and android

Comment: but atleast you can have some idea on how you can achieve that !

Comment: i know, but you are not understanding what i want to ask.

Answer (score 0):

shaqir saiyed gave a great advice with
paralaxer.com/cocos2d-x-project-setup

But I would suggest to use Copying Method of that article! It will help you to achieve not only android but others platforms as well.

What you need is Android NDK , Android SDK and Eclipse properly installed on your MAC (g)